# Glove Model Taking lots of time to give n similar words

Tags: python, nlp, stanford-nlp, word-embedding

I have a list of token and i am trying to find the top 10 similar word for each token but Glove model is taking a lot of time to return similar word.My code is:

```
class GloveModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.embedding_dict={}
        with open("glove.6B.50d", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
            for line in f:
                values = line.split()
                word = values[0]
                vector = np.asarray(values[1:], "float32")
                self.embedding_dict[word] = vector
                
    def find_closest_embeddings(self,token):
        
        return sorted(self.embedding_dict.keys(), key=lambda word: spatial.distance.euclidean(self.embedding_dict[word],token))


    def analyze(self,final_token):
        summary_txt_token=[]
        result=[]
        for i in final_token:
            if i in self.embedding_dict:
                temp=self.find_closest_embeddings(self.embedding_dict[i])[0:10] ##TOp ten similar word from the token
                summary_txt_token.extend(temp)
       
        summary_txt_token=list(set(summary_txt_token))
        return summary_txt_token
summary_obj=GloveModel()
final_token=summary_obj.analyze(final_token)
```

Comment: How large is your corpus, and how many numbers in the vector?  You're doing a distance operation (2 multiples and a sqrt) for ever word in the dictionary, for every token.

Comment: the total number of token is not around 50 to 100 only. still it get stuck

Comment: What I meant is, how many words are in `glove.6B.50d`?

Comment: It has 6 Billion token and each have 50 Features

Comment: So, this file is more than a terabyte?  You cannot possibly read the whole thing into memory.  You aren't even getting past the \__init__, much less doing 300 billion multiplies and 6 billion square root calls for EACH lookup.  You need to think about your problem in a different way.